# JS verify form data inside ajax-returned html

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ajax-returned HTML includes a table and a submit button (type=button)

The table includes jQuery routine to clone table row (each row allows choosing/uploading one file, and has two values: `<input type="text">` for doc title, and `<input type="file">`.

```
<table id="MyTable">
<tr name="tr3" id="tr3">
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="dt[]" id="dt1">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="file" name="fff[]" id="ff1">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" name="sub1" id="sub1" value="Submit" onclick="checkform();">
```

Upon form submit, I must check that each doc title has been filled-in, so the submit button calls a javascript routine:

```
function checkform()
{
    if(document.updateprojectdocs.dt[0].value=='')
    {
        alert("Fields marked with an asterisk are required.");
        document.updateprojectdocs.dt[0].focus();
        return;
    }

    document.getElementById("TheForm").submit();
}
```

Of course, this does not work (script dies before form submit -- but submits if I remove the preceeding if structure). Can anyone tell me why and how to fix?

Also, there will be an indeterminate number of `dt[]` fields to check. How could I structure a loop to do this? I suspect jQuery's .find().each() could be used, but not sure what that would look like?

---

UPDATES:

Thanks to DaHaKa's response below, I am closer to a solution. I mod'd DaHaKa's suggested code into jQuery.

I was having trouble communicating with DaHaKa - for some reason his responses were not appearing until long, long, long after he posted them (the problem was probably on my end). While I was waiting (hours), I posted part of the problem in another question and ended up resolving it there. That other question grew into the [FULL CORRECT ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430456/looping-through-array-of-dynamically-added-elements/12432993#12432993), and I direct future viewers there. Note that user `thecodeparadox` created [a working JSFiddle of the full solution](http://jsfiddle.net/BGy4M/11/).

I have awarded this question to DaHaKa as he was more than willing and able to assist, but comm problems intervened. Thanks again, D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case jQuery each function isn't neccessary, you can do it simple like this =>

try

```
<table id="MyTable">
<tr name="tr3" id="tr3">
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="dt" id="dt1">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="file" name="fff" id="ff1">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="button" name="sub1" id="sub1" value="Submit">
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("sub1").onclick = function(){
    if (document.getElementById("dt1").value!=""){
        document.getElementById("TheForm").submit();
    } else {
        alert("Empty Field(s) !");
    }
};
```

you should use `ids` in JavaScript from html tags , NOT `NAME` tags

And whats about you file input , you could understand it from your server side scripting language like php , with super global variables `$_FILES['file']['error']` types

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate both your ideas and code improvements. See my updated comment in OP. Also, uploaded files are working perfectly. I am using PHP $_FILES sgv to loop through the uploaded files and process them. Excellent ideas, thanks.

Comment: @gibberish you're welcome , but I can't understand what you are trying to do at all. could you explain it a bit more carefully