# Looping through array of dynamically-added elements

Tags: jquery

New to jQuery, requesting assistance with something I'm having trouble figuring out.

A cloned table row contains an `<input type="text" name="dt[]" id="dt1">` field. Below is the template row that gets cloned.

```
<table id="MyTable" name="MyTable">
    <tr name="tr3" id="tr3">
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="dt[]" id="dt1">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="file" name="fff[]" id="ff1">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The user could potentially create several of these fields and I am trying to figure out how to loop through them all and verify there is text in them before submitting the form.

Note that I must use the jQuery .on() method to access the form elements. How would the loop need to be coded? Initially, I've been trying this (EDITED):

```
$(document).on('click','#sub1',function() {
    var d1 = $("[name^=dt]").val();
    alert(d1);
    if (d1 !=""){
        $("#TheForm").submit();
    } else {
        alert("Empty fields!");
    }
});
```

And this:

```
var d1 = $("#dt1").val();
alert(d1);
```

And this:

```
var d1 = $("#^dt").val();
alert(d1);
```

but haven't been able to get at the data.

---

EDIT: As requested, this code clones the row:

```
$(document).on('click', '#add_row', function() {
    $("table#MyTable tr:nth-child(4)")
        .clone()
        .show()
        .find("input, span").each(function() {
            $(this)
                .val('')
                .attr('id', function(_, id) {
                    var newcnt = id + count;
                    return id + count;
                    });
        })
        .end()
        .appendTo("table")
        ;

    count++;
    if (count == 2) {
        $('#add_row').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
}); //end add_row Function
```

Comment: Id's have to be unique. Better use `name="dt[]"`

Comment: Id as in Identifier, if its not unique it no longer is an identifier.. use `class` instead. why class over other attributes cos  browsers can fallback to the native getElementsByClassName api..

Comment: Thanks gents. I should have posted more of my code (did that since). The operative word should have been "pasted" as I manually typed that initial line (what can go wrong typing 35 charadters?) and mistakenly left out the name="dt[]" bit, typing instead id="dt[]". Thanks for catching it so quickly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your HTML is not in correct format. you should do:

```
<input type="text" name="dt[]">
```

and then loop over like:

```
$('input[name^=dt]').each(function() {
  // code
  alert( this.value ); // $(this).val()
});
```

What you're trying to do can not be possible with `id` attribute, but possible with `name` attribute. ***`id` should always be unique***.

---

#### Beside that

You can use a common `class` name to all `input`s and then loop over then like:

```
$('input.common_cls').each(function() {
  // code
});
```

---

#### Note

`"#^dt"` is not a valid selector at all. Correct syntax would be

`'input[name^=dt]'`

***OR***

`input[id^=dt]`.

---

#### You may implement the validation like below

```
// this function will return true if no empty
// input exists, otherwise it will return false

function noEmptyExists() {
    return $('input[name^=dt]').filter(function() {
        return !$.trim( this.value );
    }).length === 0;
}

$(document).on('click','#sub1',function() {
   if( noEmptyExists() ) {
      alert('Success');
   } else {
      alert('Failed');
   }
});
```

***[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/zZD9a/2/)***

---

#### According to PROGRESS UPDATE

`this.val()` is wrong.

Change this line to:

```
$(this).val()
```

---

#### After a discussion in Chat and after solving the clone issue

***Full code***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = 1;
    alert('doc ready');
    var row = $("table#MyTable tr:eq(1)");
    $(document).on('click', '#sub1', function() {
        if (noEmptyExists()) {
            alert('Success');
        } else {
            alert('Failed');
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#add_row', function() {
        row.clone(true).find("input").each(function() {
            $(this).val('').attr('id', function(_, id) {
                var newcnt = id + count;
                return id + count;
            });
        }).end().appendTo("table");
    });

});

function noEmptyExists() {
    return $('input[name^=dt]').filter(function() {
        return !$.trim(this.value);
    }).length === 0;
}
```

***[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/BGy4M/11/)***

Comment: I would use class over other attributes cos browsers can fallback to the native getElementsByClassName api.

Comment: @thecodeparadox [My fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/bcmit/BGy4M/) not working but I should have clarified that it works perfectly on webserver, so the code itself is fine. I suspect the error in jsfiddle will be evident to an experienced coder (my novice errors tend to be that way). Anyway, that fiddle will allow you to compare apples with apples vis the examples.

Comment: @gibberish there is error in your PROGRESS UPDATE code.. see my update

Comment: @gibberish if you use `class=MyClass` as a `class` name to all inputs then use `input.MyClass` and so on. `common_cls` is such type of example.

Comment: @gibberish if your problem not solved after this.. then I'll continue discussion to chat `:)`

Comment: @thecodeparadox Thanks again for your help. See [this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147147/super-hero-recognition).

Comment: @gibberish you need more 25 rep to set bounty

Comment: I'm getting there... slowly but surely. It is poss to award to "old" answers. Hopefully I won't have to wrap it in Christmas paper...

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering, this is final code. There are slight modifications from `thecodeparadox`'s post only because the HTML was generated by ajax which lead to some slight differences. It is for this reason I have added this post, in case anyone else is struggling with exactly this same issue. Unlikely, but hey.

When Submit button is pressed (`<INPUT type="button">`)

```
$(document).on('click', '#sub1', function() {
    var fcnt = 0; //input-FILE
    var dcnt = 0; //input-DOCTITLE
    $('input[name^=fff]').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() == ''){fcnt=fcnt + 1;}
    });
    $('input[name^=dt]').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() == ''){dcnt=dcnt + 1;}
    });
    if (dcnt > 1) {
        alert('Fields marked with an asterisk cannot be empty');
    } else if (fcnt > 1) {
        alert('One of the files is still empty');
    }else{
        $("#TheForm").submit();
    }
});
```

---

Code to clone the table row. Here is the important difference, as I now understand (thanks tcp) that it is necessary to assign the row element to a var, and then use the var in the .clone() method.

```
$(document).on('click', '#add_row', function() {
    var row = $("table#MyTable tr:eq(3)");
    row.clone(true).find("input").each(function() {
        $(this).val('').attr('id', function(_, id) {
            var newcnt = id + count;
            return id + count;
        });
    }).end().show().appendTo("table");
}); //end add_row Function
```